# How do I correct my sql query(s) so i don't get the error "keyword UNION not expected"?

Tags: python, sql, flask, db2

I have one (possibly two) troublesome raw sql queries in a python flask API. I think the first sql query is causing this error, but I am by no means a master at sql. The database is DB2. The full error is as follows: "[SQL0199] Keyword UNION not expected. Valid tokens: FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH OPTIMIZE.". Here are my first and second sql query

First query

```sql
SELECT
    PRDATA as the_date,
    PREDR as csr,
    PRQTY as quantity,
    PRORD# as order_data, 
    PREXT as ext 
FROM DATA.DATATABLE 
WHERE CUST = {customer_number} 
limit {Limit} offset {offset_count}
union all
SELECT
    PRDATA as the_date,
    PREDR as csr,
    PRQTY as quantity,
    PRORD# as order_data, 
    PREXT as ext 
FROM DATA.DATATABLE 
WHERE CUST = {customer_number} 
limit {Limit} offset {offset_count}
```

Second query

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
from DATA.DATATABLE
WHERE PRCUST# = {customer_number}
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*)
from DATA.DATATABLE
WHERE PRCUST# = {customer_number}
```

Like I said, I am not master as SQL so any advice or a pointer towards something I could check out would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What SQL database are you using?

Comment: @ZackVT looks like DB2 based on the tags.

Comment: It is an IBM Db2. Adding that to the question details now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. It was with the first query, I removed the first`limit {Limit} offset {offset_count}` and left the second one after the union all. I suppose since I was using a union all it was thinking of it as a duplicate maybe and throwing that error. Not entirely sure